# VSCode: How to Focus to an Editor

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In my Visual Studio code extension, I currently call `workbench.action.moveEditorToNextGroup` which moves the editor in code. However, if I call any extra commands, it will use the previous editor group rather than the one I moved it to.

How can I focus to a certain editor such as the one I move to?

Comment: `workbench.action.moveEditorToNextGroup` isn't already focusing the editor that you move and thus its group?  Can you give an example of an additional command after you move the editor that doesn't use that editor or group.

Comment: what gives the editor focus is to use `vscode.open` to "open" the file again, if already open if just changes focus and make it visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `workbench.action.focusFirstEditorGroup` should do the tick.

Alternatively,

- `workbench.action.focusFirstEditorGroup`
- `workbench.action.focusSecondEditorGrou`

...

May also be what you are looking for.

[See docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) for full list

Answer (score 0):

A more powerful way to move editors is to use the `moveActiveEditor` command.

```js
 const moveTabBetweenGroupArgs = {to: "right", by: "group"};
 await vscode.commands.executeCommand('moveActiveEditor', moveTabBetweenGroupArgs);
```

The best documentation is located here: [moveActiveEditor explanation](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/8234#issuecomment-234573410).

If I call that repeatedly, it uses the editor I just moved.  So, for instance, if I move an editor to the right group, and then trigger the command again, that same editor is moved to the next right group.

The command will create a group to the right if there isn't already one there.

Unfortunately, with these options:

```js
// const moveTabBetweenGroupArgs = {to: "position", by: "group", value: 2};  // 'value' is 1-based
```

you should also be able to move an editor to a second group - even if it doesn't exist - but this form will NOT create the second group and silently fails.  I consider that a bug and will file an issue.

You can also use the `moveActiveEditor` command to move editors within groups easily with code like this:

```js
const moveTabInGroupArgs = {to: "position", by: "tab", value: targetIndex + 1};  // 'value' is 1-based
await vscode.commands.executeCommand('moveActiveEditor', moveTabInGroupArgs);
```

which will move the ACTIVE editor to the `value` column within th3e current group.  The `value` is 1-based, so the first column in a group is `1`, not `0`.